# How to convert a JSON array to comma separated string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I've a JSON column from where I'm extracting values. All goes good, except I'm not able to convert an array inside the JSON Object to a comma separated string. Below is the structure similar to what I have.

| id | name | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 234 | AAA | { "..." "options": [ "Option A", "Option B", "Option C" ], "..." } |
| ... | ... | ... |

Now I'm extracting the data like this:

```sql
SELECT
    `id`,
    `name`,
    JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT( `data`, '$.options' ) ) AS `options`
FROM `my_table`;
```

Result I'm getting:

| id | name | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 234 | AAA | ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C"] |
| ... | ... | ... |

Result I want:

| id | name | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 234 | AAA | "Option A", "Option B", "Option C" |
| ... | ... | ... |

**How can I do this in MySQL? It's like implode function in php.**

I've seen some answers that uses nested `REPLACE` but remember that the value itself may contain square brackets.

Comment: Which version of mysql you are using

Comment: @AkhileshMishra I'm using MySQL v8.0.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using mysql 8.0 then you can use `JSON_TABLE` with `CROSS JOIN` and `GROUP_CONCAT` to achieve this:

Try below query:

```
select t1.id,t1.name, group_concat(t2.data_ )
from test t1 
cross join 
json_table(t1.data->'$.options', '$[*]' columns(data_ varchar(10) path '$'))t2
group by 1,2
```

If you want to surround all the values in quotes then replace `group_concat(t2.data_ )` with `group_concat(concat('"',t2.data_,'"' ))` in above query

**Explanation**

In your question you want to get the values of `options` array of the JSON in to comma separated string. So the steps of the solution is :

**Step 1. Get the array data from JSON:** Here by using `->` operator we are able to fetch the data from `data` field. `data->'$.options'` will return the array in JSON format.

**Step 2. Unnest all the elements of the array:** Here `JSON_TABLE`([Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)) will do the things for us. see below example

```
select * from json_table(
'["Option A","Option B","Option C"]', 
'$[*]' columns(data_ varchar(10) path '$'))t

Result:

data_
Option A
Option B
Option C
```

**Step 3. Cross join the unnest records:** After unnest the array `CROSS JOIN` it with main table, which will return one row against each records returns by `JSON_TABLE`. In below example you will get 3 rows against id 234 because there are 3 elements in array.

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t2.data_
from test t1 
cross join 
json_table(t1.data->'$.options', '$[*]' columns(data_ varchar(10) path '$'))t2

Result:

id    name      data_
234   AAA       Option A
234   AAA       Option B
234   AAA       Option C
```

**Step 4. Group the results:** In final step use `GROUP_CONCAT`([Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)) to group all the records by `id`, `name` etc. to get the desired output.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8719c39087b0493243ea5e833f93449)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I put quotes in the value, I actually wanted without qoutes. Sorry for asking a bit more, can you please explain how is this working?

Comment: Beautiful explaination @AkhileshMishra .. Extremely helphull. Thanks.

Comment: group_concat is deprecated in my sql latest version